# Dart extended classes with generic types won't use the direct parent type

Tags: dart, types, abstract-class, extends

I have 2 classes (`B` and `C`) and I am trying to create a parent type `A` so I can manipulate a variable `a` of type `A`.
The following example works fine:

```dart
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class C extends A {}

var b = true;

final A a = b ? C() : B();
```

But for some reason, when `A` has a generic type `A<T>`, it doesn't work

```dart
class A<T> {}

class B extends A<int> {}

class C extends A<String> {}

var b = true;

final A a = b ? C() : B(); // <- Error
```

I get the linting error:

```
A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'A<dynamic>'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'A<dynamic>'.dart(invalid_assignment)
```

What is the reason? And can I make it work without an explicit cast `as A`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dart's [**UP**](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/resources/type-system/upper-lower-bounds.md#upper-bounds) algorithm, which is used to find an common supertype when needed, is not *that* clever. (For various reasons, including being too clever might cause it to never terminate in some cases).

Here the expression `b ? C() : B()` tries to find a common supertype of the types `C` and `B`. Their immediate super-interfaces are just `A<int>` and `A<String>` respectively, which are *unrelated types*. Neither is a subtype of the other, so neither can be used as common supertype.
Their immediate super-interfaces are both just `Object`, and thus we have a solution.
So, **UP**(`B`, `C`) is `Object`, and that's the type of `b ? C() : B()`.
(This is actually not from the linked document, the **UP** algorithm on those types falls through to the least-upper-bound algorithm of the current language specification, which gives the result `Object`).

You might have expected the algorithm to find `A<Object>` instead. All I can say is that it won't. The algorithm will only look at the types that are actually implemented by the two types being compared, where `A<String>` and `A<int>` are different unrelated types, and `A<Object>` is not actually among the interfaces implemented by either type. Their only common *implemented* type is `Object`.